# Django - Replace manually-entered primary key with AutoField

Tags: django, django-migrations

### The issue

I have a model with fields like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    [more fields not relevant to issue]
```

I think I made the wrong decision using a manually-entered CharField as my primary key, so I would like to switch to an AutoField as my primary key. Ideally the resulting schema would look like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # containing the same data id used to contain
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    [more fields not relevant to issue]
```

However, I am struggling to perform this migration, so I am looking for solutions on how to migrate to the new schema.

### What I've tried

When I make a migration that just renames `id` to `url`, any page I try to load gives an error. For example, the admin page gives an error like `MyObject has no attribute 'id'.`

I tried to add an AutoField named `autogen_id` to the model, and make that the primary key. However, when using the makemigrations command, I got the message `It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'autogen_id' to myobject without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.` and I don't know how to generate a unique value for all the existing objects (or if that would even be enough to get the schema up and running).

I have not tried to create a new database from scratch, because there are several hundred entries I would have to recreate. The database is only about 1 MB (using sqlite), so I am willing to entertain solutions that export the data and re-import it into a fresh database, but I don't know how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check settings.py in your project and add (if you don't have) this line:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

After all, delete all migrations and make new without field id in models. This line create unique id field in every model you will create.

**EDIT**

I think that you have to create save() method in your model, that will be set specific field value:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.my_id:
            last_id = MyModel.objects.order_by('-my_id').first()
            if last_id:
                self.my_id = last_id.my_id + 1
            else:
                self.my_id = 1
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Self.my_id is your start, default value.

Comment: This allows me to rename the id field to url, but if I try to make it not a primary key, Django asks for a default, which I don't know how to make autoincrement. And entering a value like 0 will cause uniqueness constraints to fail. I found a report of this same issue [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27339).

Comment: Check edit and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but before I saw it I migrated a different way. (Exporting to JSON, modifying the JSON, then importing into a fresh database. Not recommended for serious projects!)

Comment: it won't work
AutoFields must set primary_key=True.